# RXJS - Only emit bigger values than the last value

Tags: angular, functional-programming, rxjs, observable

I want to implement a scroll listener for my site with rxjs. The Listener currently emits every scrollY number. Is it possible to implement a scroll-listener that emits only the scroll position if the number is higher than before **WITHOUT STORING A STATEFULL PROPERTY**. I would like to solve this only with operators. Current implementation looks like this:

```
  public lastScrolledHeight: number = 0;
  ...
  public ngOnInit() {
    this.listenForScroll()
      .subscribe(scrollHeight => {
        this.showAddButton = this.lastScrolledHeight >= scrollHeight; // true or false
        this.lastScrolledHeight = scrollHeight;
      });
  }

  private listenForScroll(): Observable<number> {
    return fromEvent(window, 'scroll').pipe(
      debounceTime(25),
      map((e: any) => e.path[1].scrollY)
    );
  }
```

### hints

One approach already could be adding the `startsWith(0)` operator. That would emit the initial position to 0. But if `scan()`, `filter()` or `reduce()` would help, i cant tell.

### usecase

I scroll down to Y=300. 300 should be emitted. I scroll up to Y= 50. Nothing should be emitted. I scroll again down to 150, 150 should be emitted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`scan`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/scan.html) operator along with [`distinctUntilChanged`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/distinctuntilchanged.html):

```
return fromEvent(window, 'scroll').pipe(
  debounceTime(25),
  map((e: any) => e.path[1].scrollY),
  scan((prev, curr) => Math.max(prev, curr), 0),
  distinctUntilChanged()
)
```

What happens is the observable is modified to contain the max value of the current and previous iteration (and has the value 0 as it's initial value).

After that, the `distinctUntilChanged()` makes sure that repeated events are not emitted by the observable.

This ensures that you will only receive values that are greater than the previous one.

Comment: While I really enjoyed simplicity of this approach, it seems that it will emit only increasing scrolling position, and wont emit if user would scroll down then up then down again, [see this example](https://observable-playground.github.io/gist/a69f909dbb8dfe43e459beaa1a004d18). Still, nice usage of `scan` here

Answer (score 3):

I guess, you could use pairwise for that:

```ts
source$.pipe(
  startWith(-1),
  pairwise(),
  switchMap(([a,b])=>
    b > a
    ? of(b)
    : EMPTY
  )
)
```

[image: RXJS - Only emit bigger values than the last value]

Check this code [in a playground](https://thinkrx.io/gist/344486194ac5eaee28cf09697e1684af)

Hope this helps

Comment: I'll test that out, as soon as possible! Fun fact: A part of my bachelor thesis was about RxJS and still there its uncredible how much I  still dont know.^^

Comment: @creep-story, yeah, there are so many things about FRP! Be sure to check that playground I linked -- might help you get better view on Rx and other FRP libs! Also, I now think that the option suggested by Daniel looks better.

Comment: @creep-story, I've added another answer with custom operator. I think that approach should be preferable over this one. / *for a moment I thought that a simple distinctUntilChanged with a predicate would solve your problem, but it turned out that it compares previously **passed** value with the new one, while you need to compare **any** previous value with the new one* /

Comment: your appraoch works just fine with the custom operator, however i would appriciate if you check out also my solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

Being dissatisfied with my previous approach, I decided to create a custom operator that encompasses `rxjs.filter` and will use a predicate to compare current value to the previous one:

```js
// it will take a predicate to compare values
// by default it will behave as distinctUntilChanged()
const filterChanges = (predicate = ((a,b) => a!==b)) => {
  // store previous value
  let prevValue = void 0;
  return pipe(
    filter((value, index)=>{
      // pass through the first value on stream
      if (index === 0) {
        prevValue = value;
        return value;
      }

      // compare current with prev
      const result = predicate(value, prevValue);
      prevValue = value;
      return result;
    })
  );
};
```

And then its as simple as passing a comparator:

```js
source$.pipe(
  filterChanges((a, b) => a > b)
)
```

The output:

[image: filter changes custom operator]

Heres a [playground example](https://thinkrx.io/gist/f649d408cfdad2c560ad70031354f0af).

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

While I'm so thankfull for the help of @Kos and @Daniel for putting the time in to help me get a clean solution I've found out an approach which is clean and simple.

```
fromEvent(document, 'scroll').pipe(
      debounceTime(50),
      // get scrollY
      map((e: any) => e.path[1].scrollY),
      startWith(0),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      // map the last scroll values into an array
      pairwise(),
      // returns true if delta of prev & curr is greaterOrEqual 0 => scroll up
      map(([prev, curr]: Array<number>) => prev - curr >= 0)
    );
```

Comment: Well, thats totally cool if you're going to do if-else later. Couple of things: you'll probably want to move `distinctUntilChanged` downwards -- afaik, document wont emit scroll event w/o changes. Place `startWith` after the map and have just `startWith(0)`. And you definitely don't need a `Boolean(..)`, just `prev-curr >= 0` is already a boolean

Comment: Yeah you're right,lol.^^ But I dont need any if/else to do anymore. :)

Comment: what about "if true then scroll up"? )

Comment: ahh you mean this... yeah my subscribe just looks like this:  ... `.subscribe(show => this.showAddButton = show);`

Comment: Cool :) Yeah, well, our solutions were aimed at filtering, not mapping. Have fun Rx-ing!

Comment: `distinctUntilChanged()` can be helpful in situation where there is also an vertical scroll, in that case events will be fired with the same `scrollY` value. I would just change the map at the bottom to `filter(([prev, next]) => next > prev)` so the observable will not emit all values, just the ones that are higher. Unless I got something wrong :)

Comment: Honestly, I had to mark @Kos answer as the right answer, because my initial question was also leaning to filter the values not to map them. Needed to correct this. Thanks!

Comment: We probably should've asked for more details :) What @MaksymCierzniak might meant with the first part is that `distinctUntilChanged` can be moved to the far bottom, e.g. `map-startWith-pairwise-map-distinctUntilChanged`. Maybe I'd also moved the debounce to be the last -- you gotta play here to test the performance.